# Dynamically assign dataframes to an object inside a for statement

Tags: python, pandas

I have 4 dataframes with data :

final_101

final_102

final_103

final_104

I want to print them into a single text file by calling them dynamically by their last digits. I tried using the below code but I am not able to make it work as the dynamic step just gives a string value instead of the dataframe:

```
file_extension = ['101', '102', '103', '104']

with open(f"myfile_{timestamp}.txt", mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
  for names in file_extension :
        f.write("\n" + f"{names}_data" + "\n")
        new_file = 'final_'+str(names)
        new_file.loc['Total'] = new_file['samp'].sum()
        f.write("\n"+str(new_file)+"\n")
```

The step `new_file = 'final_'+str(names)` just gives a string value to new_file but not the data. Is there a way to dynamically call the object?

Note : The files final_101, final_102, final_103, final_104 are in memory an not in any file location.

**Correct solution for this code is below**
*also sabik has mentioned different scenarios in which they can be used*.

```
dfs = {'101' : final_101, '102': final_102, '103': final_103, '104': final_104}

with open(f"myfile_{timestamp}.txt", mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as out_f:
  for i, (key, df) in enumerate(dfs.items()):
        out_f.write("\n" + f"{key}_data" + "\n")
        new_file = df.copy()
        new_file.loc['Total'] = new_file['samp'].sum()
        out_f.write("\n"+str(new_file)+"\n")
```

Comment: "I want to print them into a single text file by calling them dynamically by their last digits." don't try to use variables dynamically like that. Instead, *use a container like a list or a dict*

Comment: I am able write it separately by repeating the write lines 4 times but not able to understand who to do it using a function.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Can you please explain a bit more? Sorry, I am a bit new to this logic so trying to make sense of what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(updated per comments...)

It's possible to retrieve variables by name in python, but not really recommended.

If there's just the four, you can hard-code them easily enough:

```
dfs = [final_101, final_102, final_103, final_104]

with open(f"myfile_{timestamp}.txt", mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as out_f:
  for i, df in enumerate(dfs):
    header = i == 0  # only write out the header for the first one
    df.to_csv(out_f, header=header)
```

If you have a variable number, the best way to change the code generating them so that it puts the data into a dict, so that they're called `final[101]` or `final['101']` (depending on whether the 101 is better thought of as a number or as a text label). Then you'll be able to iterate over `final.items()`, like this:

```
with open(f"myfile_{timestamp}.txt", mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as out_f:
  for i, (key, df) in enumerate(final.items()):
    header = i == 0  # only write out the header for the first one
    # optionally write out key here
    df.to_csv(out_f, header=header)
```

If you absolutely must look up variables by name, you can check `globals()`; it's not really recommended in everyday programming, though.

Comment: It shows "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'final_101'". . But the file exist as a dataframe in the environment.

Comment: `with open(f"{names}_data") as in_f:` this doesn't open a dataframe

Comment: Ah, are these variables in memory rather than files?

Comment: Right, that's a completely different question, then :-)

Comment: oh ok! Actually the 4 files(final_101 to final_104) are in memory . I want to collate these 4 files in one and write it to text file (myfile.txt) using open()

Comment: Do you need their names, or just the contents?

Comment: thanks! this is what I needed. I just made small changes to fit my need and have updated the code in the question section.

Comment: BTW, if you don't end up using `i`, you can omit the `enumerate` and just use: `for key, df in dfs.items():`